# Apache log for 301

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, httpd.conf

How can i create a log file for 301 redirects, based on response header?

I know that i can use `SetEnvIf` with `CutsomLog`, but it seems `SetEnvIf` has access just for request, no for response.

Answer (score 0):

If your using mod_rewrite you could enable the RewriteLog  e.g.

```
RewriteLog /var/log/http/rewrite.log
RewriteLogLevel 1
```